# How to get the app a Django model is from?

Tags: django, model

I have a model with a generic relation:

```
TrackedItem --- genericrelation ---> any model
```

I would like to be able to generically get, from the initial model, the tracked item.

I should be able to do it on any model without modifying it.

To do that I need to get the content type and the object id. Getting the object id is easy since I have the model instance, but getting the content type is not: ContentType.object.filter requires the model (which is just `content_object.__class__.__name__`) and the app_label.

I have no idea of how to get in a reliable way the app in which a model is.

For now I do `app = content_object.__module__.split(".")[0]`, but it doesn't work with django contrib apps.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You don't need to get the app or model just to get the contenttype - there's a handy method to do just that:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

ContentType.objects.get_for_model(myobject)
```

Despite the name, it works for both model classes and instances.

Comment: Is it? Doesn't this hit the database?

Comment: @meshy yes but django ContentType uses a cache on it's manager so it only queries once per model.

Comment: The import is: from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

Comment: Use `.app_label` to get the app string from the ContentType object returned by `get_for_model()` method. I added an example below. Hope to be helpful.

Answer (score 119):

The `app_label` is available as an attribute on the `_meta` attribute of any model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
print(User._meta.app_label)
# The object name is also available
print(User._meta.object_name)
```

Comment: I think @DanielRoseman's answer is better since it doesn't require access to the private member `_meta`

Comment: @AddisonKlinke maybe but to be fair his answer requires an import and a database hit

Comment: `_meta` isn't private, it's prefixed to avoid collisions with user-created model fields. It's documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/meta/

Comment: IIRC whilst `_meta` is public, `app_label` is not (per the Django documentation). That said, I don't recall it changing for years and years, so I happily use it.

Answer (score 9):

You can get both `app_label` and `model` from your object using the built-in **ContentType** class:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user_obj = User.objects.create()
obj_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(user_obj)

print(obj_content_type.app_label)
# u'auth'
print(obj_content_type.model)
# u'user'
```

This is better approach respect of using the `_meta` properties that are defined for private purposes.