# How can I get the name of app inside a model?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write model mixin, that will give me direct link to admin edite form:

```
class EditLinkMixin(models.Model):
    def get_admin_link(self):
        return '/admin/%s/%s/%d/' % (app_name, self.__class__.__name__, self.pk)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

It will help to content managers to edit some article by one click (if he has a permission).
The question is: how can I get app_name? Also, can I some way get a name of main app, that has module settings.py and is entry point of the project? It will help to get direct access to subclass declare from some reusable app...

Thanks for advices!

Comment: Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2742722/842935

Comment: Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000205/how-to-get-an-app-name-using-python-in-django and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256295/how-to-get-current-application-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Model._meta.app_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label)

Plus: If you're creating a mixin you don't need to extend it from `models.Model` and make it abstract. You can create a regular class:

```
class EditLinkMixin(object):
    def get_admin_link(self):
        return '/admin/%s/%s/%d/' % (self._meta.app_name, self.__class__.__name__, self.pk)

class MyModel(models.Model, EditLinkMixin):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! About abstract: it work fine if I define method, but if I need to declare some fields in my mixin - it should be abstract subclass of models.Model class. Am I right?.. And what about main app? How can I get string with app_name of main app, in any reusable app?

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you need to add fields you'll have to make a an abstract model. I didn't get the last part.