# Get application name in Django model

Tags: django, django-models

The following is the model for a Django app. Let the app be called MyApp. The idea is for every app to have it's folder under the MEDIA_ROOT.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    .... #Other fields
    datoteka = models.FileField(upload_to = 'MyApp',null = True)
```

Is there a way to get the name of the app from somewhere and remove the hardcoded `MyApp`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6000205/1214214) is a similar question, however I have no access to the request object in the model.

Answer (score 15):

There is an attribute `app_label` in `_meta` attribute. Please see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742689/how-to-get-the-app-a-django-model-is-from)

Comment: Couldn't get it to work.
When i changed the `upload_to = 'MyApp'` to `upload_to = 'MyModel._meta.app_label'` i couldn't star the Django shell anymore. Got an error `NameError: name 'MyModel' is not defined`.

Comment: @Alan, try the contentType solution. It should work fine, I will see why it is not.

Comment: Try self. Instead of app name

Answer (score 3):

```
from os import path

def _get_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return path.join(instance._meta.app_label, 'subdir', filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ....
    datoteka = models.FileField(upload_to=_get_upload_to, ...)
```

Will result in 'MyApp/subdir' upload path.